# Jquery Mobile - how to table + search bar

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to code a table with column toggle in my page but I want it to have a search bar in the top too.. I've tried in many ways but I had two problems, first, the search bar began to search for the toogle button text of the table, second, the search bar was searching the elements of the table but it gained height and it was hidding the toogle button... What's the best way to implement the search bar here ?

the code of the table:

```
<table data-role="table" id="my-table" data-mode="columntoggle"
            class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive"
            data-column-btn-theme="b" data-column-btn-text="Colunas"
            data-column-popup-theme="a">

<thead>
    <tr class="ui-bar-d">
        <th data-priority="1">ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th data-priority="2">Ano</th>
        <th data-priority="3">Descrição</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td>Citizen Kane</td>
        <td>1941</td>
        <td>100%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>2</th>
        <td>Casablanca</td>
        <td>1942</td>
        <td>97%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>3</th>
        <td>The Godfather</td>
        <td>1972</td>
        <td>97%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>4</th>
        <td>Gone with the Wind</td>
        <td>1939</td>
        <td>96%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <td>Lawrence of Arabia</td>
        <td>1962</td>
        <td>94%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>6</th>
        <td>Dr. Strangelove Or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and
            Love the Bomb</td>
        <td>1964</td>
        <td>92%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>7</th>
        <td>The Graduate</td>
        <td>1967</td>
        <td>91%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>8</th>
        <td>The Wizard of Oz</td>
        <td>1939</td>
        <td>90%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>9</th>
        <td>Singin' in the Rain</td>
        <td>1952</td>
        <td>89%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <td>Inception</td>
        <td>2010</td>
        <td>84%</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fr8Yd/2/)**

```
<form>
    <input id="filterTable-input" data-type="search" />
</form>
<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" id="movie-table" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterTable-input" class="ui-responsive table-stroke" data-column-btn-theme="b" data-column-btn-text="Colunas" data-column-popup-theme="a">
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't knew about that data-input.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Any way to make this side by side?

Comment: @ezanker: note that you can remove the tag <form> :)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this ?

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="search-2">Search Input:</label>
<input type="search" name="search-2" id="search-2" value="" />
</div>
```